# How to fix "Exception in main! locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid" when starting monerod?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-cli

If you have upgraded to 17.1.0 of the monero wallet software and run into the error

```
Exception in main! locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

... when starting monerod

Comment: I have a simple question:
Can't we use the startup flags located in settings, node to set the argument there?
And if yes, how do we do? I tried the argument without success.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Simply add

```
LANG=C LC_ALL=C
```

infront of the `./monerod` command...

The entire command could look something like this:

```
LANG=C LC_ALL=C /home/$USER/monero-x86_64-linux-gnu-v0.17.1.0/monerod
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:
Even when it work fine adding **LANG=C LC_ALL=C** before the command, there is another solution useful in certain cases.

Can happen when you login over ssh from a **Mac** to a linux box, and **your terminal automatically sets environment variables**. There's a checkbox for that. Uncheck it, and you're good to go.

In iTerm it's in the profile -> Terminal tab.

In Terminal, it's in the Terminal -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Advanced tab, uncheck "Set locale environment variables at startup"